# How to select posts and shared posts together?

Tags: mysql

I have a system that users can do posts and share posts from another friends, like on facebook.

The problem is I'd like to fetch data from posts and shared posts together, I mean, in the order but posts are on table posts and shared posts on table share:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `titulo` text,
  `data` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `share` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `share_post_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `data` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I have this select to get posts:

```
select c.nome, c.user, p.user, p.id, p.data, p.titulo, pp.foto, count(DISTINCT likes.user) as likes_count, count(distinct comentarios.id) as comentarios_count, count(DISTINCT l2.user) as count2 from posts p 
join cadastro c on p.user=c.id 
left join profile_picture pp on p.user = pp.user
left join likes on likes.post = p.id
left join comentarios on comentarios.foto = p.id and comentarios.delete = 0  
left join likes l2 on l2.post = p.id and l2.user = ?
group by p.id
order by p.id desc limit 20
```

how can I get shared posts together with the posts in this select? any ideas?

Comment: just add an union to this same query adding a join to share table. Do the counts in an outer query... use the union as subquery

Comment: @JorgeCampos thank you for your answer! can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by simply doing union all and adding missing column as NULL like!

```
     SELECT id,`user`,`data`,`titulo`,NULL as `share_post_id` from posts 
     union all 
     SELECT  id,`user`,`data`,NULL as `titulo`,`share_post_id` from `share`     order by id
```

Comment: thank you friend!! and where shoud I add the counts?

Comment: Well you can treat my answer query as derived table give it an alias and do whatever you want either join and count with any table. As I don't know about your complete schema, so you have to effort.